# Saving lines of script to a text file?

Tags: python

I am wondering would it be possible to save few line of code (as it is)  from a script (in python) to a textile  while running the script in Pycharm which  I run every time with new arguments, and I would like to save these arguments with other results automatically, so that I can know which arguments leads to which results, I don't have to add them manually and it's automatically saved in text file to my path.

Example!

For example  I want to save the following line of python code from the script  to a text file so that I can know I have multiplied the `loss2` with 0.75:

```
"return loss + 0.75*loss2"
```

OR

```
"self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(80, return sequences=False,return_state=False),merge mode='ave')"
```

I want to save these kind of scripts (while running) it as a text file specifically in Pycharm.

Comment: There's nothing that will do this automatically, but you can simply write a formatted string containing the variable values to a file.

Comment: It would be possible to define a function decorator that automatically saved the arguments passed to the function to a file as well as the result the function returned.